# Auto-Updating in Console Application

Tags: c#

I have a console Application that Asks The user to answer question, The score is display at the upper-right of the screen, I want the score to be auto-Updates when a user gives a correct answer.

```
    public void L1Timer()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int ch = 0, score = 0;
        Console.Write("Chances : " + ch);
        Console.CursorLeft = 40;
        Console.Write("Marks : " + score);
        for (int time = 0; time <= 100000; time++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 0);
            Console.Write("Time Elapsed : " + time + " Secs");
            Console.CursorLeft = 40;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void Level1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.CursorLeft = 40;
        Console.WriteLine("C _ _ E _ _ _ T _ _ N");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        int tot = 0;
        while (tot != 70)
        {
            Console.Write("Guess : ");
            string gues = Console.ReadLine();
            if ((gues == "E") || (gues == "L") || (gues == "B") || (gues == "R"))
            {
                 tot += 10;
            } 
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VocEnhancer VE = new VocEnhancer();
        Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart (VE.L1Timer));
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\n");
        Thread T2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(VE.Level1));

        T1.Start();
        T2.Start();
    }
```

This is my Code...I don't know what to add to auto-update the scores.

Comment: Windows Forms application instead of Console. Really simple. It's like asking to fly to the sky with a private car. It's not meant for such usage.

Comment: `int score;
if(answer is correct){
score++;
}`

Comment: Show your code so we can easily help you.. :)

Comment: I have added my code..Pls help me edit it

Comment: @Precioustj +1 for providing the code

Comment: Ignoring the fancy display issues, in L1Timer() and Level1(), you're declaring the relevant variables as **local** ones.  This means they are only accessible to that method.  If you want both methods to be able to access those values then they need to be moved out to a higher scope in your VocEnhancer() class.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, we can only assume and my suggestion as follows:

```
string question = "CEO of Microsoft";
string actualAnswer ="STEVE BALLMER";
Console.WriteLine(question);
string userAnswer = "";
Console.WriteLine(userAnswer);
int score = 0;
if(actualAnswer.Trim() == userAnswer.ToUpper().Trim())
{
score++;
}
```

Comment: @Precioustj for each guess, will you add up score `tot`?

Answer (score 0):

First a warning: console is not meant to display graphics, menus, or to be drawn on. It is meant to be written upon, one line at the time. For all things graphics there are windows, and windows should be used, not consoles. However, if you are just playing around and making fun at your leisure time then go ahead and write characters at strange places in the console.

To move the cursor use [SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) method. To find out where the cursor currently is use [CursorLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx) and [CursorTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx) properties. When you want to write something at fixed coordinates save current cursor position, change to fixed position, write the text, and change back to old position.

But what should happen when all text reaches the end of the screen, and text at the top disappears? Well, there are ways to solve this, but don't bother. Just use window instead of console.

Comment: That is what we were told to do in our project

Comment: @Precioustj are you being told to write something at the top of the console screen? That's hard to believe. If you are being told to make a console project then just do it simple, line by line, and no this fancy stuff.